# Simple SQL code in EXEC throwing an error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, exec

This is in relation to my previous question. I am running a exec statement as below and I get an error Incorrect syntax near '+@dbname+'.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
exec('
declare @dbname nvarchar(100)
set @dbname = ''HUM_FM_1_SYNTQ_TEST''

select @dbname

Select seriesvariables_value from
(
select *, row_number() over 
(order by SeriesVariables_ID asc) as rownum from ''+@dbname+''
.dbo.Seriesvariables where 
SeriesVariables_Label = ''Enter Tablet Segment Pull Date'' and
Series_ID = 42) as tbl1 
where rownum = 1')
```

Comment: Instead of `''+@dbname+''` use `'+@dbname+'`only.

Comment: @R.S And op also needs to declare and assign the variable outside the `EXEC`

Comment: Hi Marc. This is for SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Hi R.S @dbname is declared inside the exec so am still getting an error using what you have suggested. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to dynamically choose what database you're running this query on.  You can do when you are creating the query your are going to `exec`, but you can't have a variable in your query that represents the database.

This should work

```
declare @dbname nvarchar(100)
set @dbname = 'HUM_FM_1_SYNTQ_TEST'

exec('

select @dbname

Select seriesvariables_value from
(
select *, row_number() over 
(order by SeriesVariables_ID asc) as rownum from '+@dbname+'
.dbo.Seriesvariables where 
SeriesVariables_Label = ''Enter Tablet Segment Pull Date'' and
Series_ID = 42) as tbl1 
where rownum = 1')
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. Is there anyway I can have @dbName declared inside the exec.

Comment: Not and use it as the database name in that query.  Why don't you want to declare it outside of the exec statement?

Comment: Hi I have modified my script as you have suggested and it works fine. Thanks ever so much.